# urllib.urlretrieve() is not working after importing the library

Tags: python

I imported urllib module and tried to use urllib.urlretrieve() function with some arguments. Then it got the error "attributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'urlretrieve'"

I tried with both python 2x and 3x.

```
import urllib
import json
import requests
count=1
req=requests.get("http://meme-api.herokuapp.com/gimme")
json_data = json.loads(req.text)
imgs="memes-"+str(count)+".jpg"
print(imgs)
urllib.urlretrieve(json_data["url"],imgs)
print(imgs + "is saved")
```

"attributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'urlretrieve'"

Comment: on Python 3.x `import urllib.request` and `urllib.request.urlretrieve()`

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: I'm new to stackoverflow, I will definitely post future questions with that information in mind. Thank you @furas

Comment: strange is that you have problem in 2.x because it is correct code for 2.x. You could have this problem if you created own file `urllib.py` (or subfolder `urllib`) in the same folder where you run script because then `import urllib` would load your file `urllib.py` instead of module `urllib`.

Comment: Yep, I had a file with that name in the directory, I renamed the file and the code works fine. Thank you @furas .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use urlib.request.urlretrieve() instead of urllib.retrieve()

```
import urllib.request
import json
import requests
count=1
req=requests.get("http://meme-api.herokuapp.com/gimme")
json_data = json.loads(req.text)
imgs="memes-"+str(count)+".jpg"
print(imgs)
urllib.request.urlretrieve(json_data["url"],imgs)
print(imgs + "is saved")
```